# Which rule to choose for NIntegrate?

Tags: numerical-integration

I would like to know how to choose the right rule among several (`TrapezoidalRule`, `NewtonCotesRule`, ...) to compute correctly an integral with `NIntegrate`. For example, the integral below gives different values for different rules. What is the exact value of this integral?

```
a = 2;
b = 3;
c = 20;

NIntegrate[Exp[-(c/Sqrt[1 - x^2])]/((x + (a - 1)/b) (x-(a - 1)/b)), {x, 0, 1}]
(*-1.0000653404629316`*^-8*)

NIntegrate[Exp[-(c/Sqrt[1 - x^2])]/((x + (a - 1)/b) (x -(a - 1)/b)), {x,0, (a - 1)/b, 1},Method -> "PrincipalValue"]
(*-5.9849005*10^-9*)

NIntegrate[Exp[-(c/Sqrt[1 - x^2])]/((x + (a - 1)/b) (x - (a - 1)/b)), {x, 0, 1},Method -> "TrapezoidalRule"]
(*-8.7629982*10^-9*)

NIntegrate[Exp[-(c/Sqrt[1 - x^2])]/((x + (a - 1)/b) (x - (a - 1)/b)), {x, 0, 1},Method -> "NewtonCotesRule"]
 (*-2.8357144*10^-9*)
```

Comment: integrand blows up at x=1/3  so all the above numerical answers are wrong  :)

Comment: @Nasser how this? How to get the exact value?

Comment: **How to get the exact value** there is no exact value since integral does not converge between zero and 1.  What happens to the integrand when x=1/3? (using the values you gave above for a,b,c).

Comment: Is it possible to calculate it in the complex plane?

Comment: @Nasser, please how to ask MATHEMATICA to compute this integral with the condition `(a - 1)/b < 1`?

Comment: You can use Assumptions. But `Intergate` still can not do it. `Integrate[
 Exp[-(c/Sqrt[1 - x^2])]/((x + (a - 1)/b) (x - (a - 1)/b)), {x, 0, 1},
  Assumptions -> (a - 1)/b < 1]`  screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPAHk.png)